# Windows Server 2008 R2 scheduler ignores "hidden" setting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have the following problem: I've created scheduled jobs that are only containing calls to a cmd and have parameters that contain things like project name etc.

I know about the fact that you have to set it to "Run only when user is logged on" if you want to see the window (cmd in this case) and also have to uncheck "hidden".

Until a week or two ago that worked fine, the box was showing up. Now the exact same job does no longer show the dos box. I suspect a windows update but I couldn't find anything useful in the update history of the server.

Do you guys have any idea what it might be? I tried switching the settings between the two "run as" options, tried setting it to hidden, tried switching "configure for" around...

The jobs run ok most of the time, the output is generated in most cases but if things go wrong I want to see the shell and not have to pipe everything to a .txt :/ 
I tried looking on google etc for a solution but only found other problems or the "my tasks run hidden if I choose run whether user is logged on or not" solutions.

Any ideas or hints? Anything would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use scheduler to automate running of some rutine task, what's the point of manually checking/controlling it's execution? It is sort of negates benefit of automation and should be done through some basic logging (you can built in in your task scripts or whatever it is) and even viewer where you can check whether your tasks was run successfully. 
Why it is required to you to see this window? Are you really need it?
If you state that it used to work OK then check logs does your tasks run successfully all the tine but hidden from you or it's something else? 
Try to re-create / create new task & check whether it is not run hidden with settings you use.

 From your description your scheduled task indeed configured so that it should be visible, namely:

- It is scheduled under your current logon account.
- It is configured to Run only when user is logged on.

These 2 conditions required for task to be visible.

Comment: The tasks process data and although they run quite well every now and again they crash for various reasons so while it is not required to see the window it is helpful. The machine does nothing else, it is not like someone gets interrupted in his/her work.

currently we pipe the whole output to a .txt file but it seems so stupid to pipe everything which would be visible anyway. On the other hand the .cmd's are pretty old => not that good log support :(

I created new tasks and made sure that they run under the correct login and I check the "only run when logged on" box but still nothing =(

Comment: The problem just drives me insane since I expect a task scheduler to actually do what it is told (in this case run a job and show me the window). Then, on the other hand, this is windows so I am not really sure why I am crying. Even I have seen programs that ran for ~10-15 years break from one day to the next one ._."

I'll probably go looking for another way to do those jobs (perhaps rewriting some parts and adding some logging),  hopefully without relying on task scheduler to start them.

Comment: Now it is working again as expected =.= Didn't show the window for a week or so and now they are there like nothing ever happened. I am sorry to say that I don't know what fixed this (reboot didn't help before) but I am glad everything is back to normal. Thanks Mikhail for the response, I guess your answer is as close as it will ever get so I'll mark it as the solution :)

Now I just have to add some real logging to the scripts so I am not reliant on the cmd windows anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `Hidden` checkbox in the Windows Task Scheduler has nothing to do with how the scheduled program is displayed (in fact, there are no display options for scheduled tasks like there are with shortcuts). The `Hidden` checkbox controls whether or not the task is displayed in the Task Scheduler. If you set check it, then Task Scheduler will not display it unless the `View Hidden Tasks` option in the `View` menu is selected. You should still see the program window when it runs even if it is checked.

You did not indicate what changes you had made to the task between the time it worked and when it stopped, but one change that would prevent the window from being shown is if you had changed the account that runs it to the `SYSTEM` account. That is a trick that people use to hide the window (which is not a good solution, especially since there are much safer options), so if you had changed that, then you would not see it.

(The OP may have already fixed this by now), but if anyone else has the same problem, check the user account. If the task is not too complicated, you could do as Mikhail suggested and re-create the task from scratch.